# JSON.stringify() losing nested properties I know the cause but don't know the answer

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I have 2 objects:

```
const subscription = {
 endpoint: "dfksjfklsjkld",
 keys: {
    pkey: "dfsfsdfsf",
    auth: "dfsdfsdfsd"
 }
};

const extra = {
  email: "dfsdfs",
  ip:"231342.342.342.34"
};
```

I would like to put the `extra` object inside subscription, so it looks like:

```
subsciption = {
 endpoint: ......
 keys: {...},
 extra: {
    email:....,
    ip: .....
 }
}
```

then I need to send it as body of a http request:

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
  method: "PUT", 
  mode: "no-cors",
  cache: "no-cache",
  credentials: "same-origin", 
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  redirect: "follow", 
  referrerPolicy: "no-referrer", 
  body: JSON.stringify(subscription), 
});
```

but I found no matter what I do, I always lose the extra property inside subscription in the process of `JSON.stringify()`.

I know the cause: it's because that the properties in extra object are not enumerable.

So far, I have tried:

**1.use the spread:**

```
newSub = {
  ...subscription,
  ...extra
}
```

but the content of newSub will be exactly same with extra, the properties of subscription are all lost.

**2.add toJSON function into the place where I generate the extra object**

```
getExtra() : {    
.......
return {
      city: ipObject.city,
      country: ipObject.country_name,
      ip: ipObject.ip,
      lat: ipObject.latitude,
      lng: ipObject.longitude,
      org: ipObject.org,
      postal: ipObject.postal,
      region: ipObject.region,
      toJSON: () => {
        return this;
      }
    };    
}
```

no effect at all.

I attach my code here:

```
async function updateSubscription() {
  try {
    const allowed = await askForPermission();
    if (!allowed) return;

    let subscription = await getSubscription();
    if (!subscription) return;

    // email
    const email = getEmail();
    if (!email || !validateEmail(email)) {
      alert("huh...so how are you going to receive notifications?");
      return;
    }

    // ip
    let ipObject = await getIP();
    let extra = {};
    if (ipObject) {
      ipObject.email = email;
      extra = ipObject;
    } else {
      extra.email = email;
    }

    console.log("extra: ", extra);

    // var newSubscription = Object.assign({}, subscription, {extra});
    // const newSubscription = {
    //   ...subscription,
    //   extra
    // };
    let newSubscription = subscription;
    newSubscription["extra"] = extra;
    console.log("new subscription1: ", newSubscription);
    console.log("new subscription1 stringified: ", JSON.stringify(newSubscription));

    const successful = await saveRegistration(newSubscription);

    if (successful) alert("you have successfully subscribed to the DC monitor");
    else alert("shit happens, try it later");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("updateSubscription() failed: ", err);
  }
}

async function getSubscription() {
  console.log("try to get subscription");
  try {
    const swRegistration = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
    const pushSubscription = await swRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription();
    console.log("pushSubscription: ", pushSubscription);
    return pushSubscription;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("getSubscription() error: ", error);
    return null;
  }
}
```

### Update

1.Tried 1 more approach:

```
var newSubscription = Object.assign({}, subscription, {extra});
console.log("subscription: ", newSubscription);
console.log("subscription stringified: ", JSON.stringify(newSubscription));
```

here is the output screenshot:

[image]

2.Also this one:

```
 const newSubscription = {
      ...subscription,
      extra
    };
    console.log("new subscription: ", newSubscription);
    console.log("new subscription stringified: ", JSON.stringify(newSubscription));
```

And here is the screenshot of output:

[image]

3.with string index approach:

```
let newSubscription = subscription;
    newSubscription["extra"] = extra;
    console.log("new subscription1: ", newSubscription);
    console.log("new subscription1 stringified: ", JSON.stringify(newSubscription));
```

[image]

Comment: Why are the extra properties not enumerable? What kind of special object is it?

Comment: what is `subscriptionObject` ?

Comment: where is `subscriptionObject` set?

Comment: You could create a helper function that converts an object's own non-enumerable properties to enumerable properties? (on a new object) But how is the object created that its properties are not enumerable? Is there a reason for making them not enumerable?

Comment: @Cid sorry, it's subscription. I updated that

Comment: should already produce an error since `subscription` is a `const` while it gets reassigned.

Comment: @messerbill not if `subscription.extra = ...` is done

Comment: @Cid yes but the OP posted this: `subsciption = {
 endpoint: ......
 keys: {...},
 extra: {
    email:....,
    ip: .....
 }
}` which reassigns `subscription`

Comment: @messerbill sorry, it's subscription. I updated that

Comment: Ah, true good catch

Comment: `newSub = {
  ...subscription,
  extra
}`. You don't want to spread `extra`, but add it as a property of `newSub`

Comment: @FelixKling please take a look my getExtra() method. I don't do anything to make it not enumerable. I actually feel odd why the properties in extra object are not enumerable. Could you help please?

Comment: @Jcl thanks man, please see my update section, I tried your way, but the content of newSub is overwritten by extra, all properties of sub are lost

Comment: @Franva there must be something else going on... it works perfectly here (open console and run): https://jsfiddle.net/d0ajr27z/

Comment: @FelixKling I know you are suspecting the subscription itself is empty, but I do have console.log(sub), it shows contents correctly.

Comment: If this is how you create `subscription` then the properties will be enumerable. *edit:* yeah, I got confused by the different approaches. But it looks like `subscription` really is an instance of `PushSubscription`? How is that created?

Comment: @Jcl I copied my code as-is into the question. Please take a look. thanks

Comment: @FelixKling okie, I now posted the getSubscription() method. please see my updated code.

Comment: Maybe explicitly copy the properties you need from that object? Since it's a host object you can't really make any assumptions about how it's implemented (I think). According to the spec it actually implements its own JSON serialization procedure. So maybe you want to do `sub = subscription.toJSON(); sub.extra = extra; JSON.stringify(sub)` instead.

Comment: yes, this is the cause, the issue comes from the PushAPI. thanks man ~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If mutating `subscription` is OK, you can just use:

```
subscription['extra'] = extra;
```

If you want a new object, you can use:

```
const subscriptionObject = Object.assign({}, subscription, { extra });
```

---

**EDIT:** Since you are working with the [Push API](https://www.w3.org/TR/push-api/), the properties in `PushSubscription` are not enumerable. So the `subscription` object does not behave quite like a normal object, which is why the suggested approaches have not been working.

However, you can serialize the push subscription using [`PushSubscription.toJSON()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushSubscription/toJSON) first to serialize it to a "normal" object, then use one of the suggested techniques:

```
subscriptionObject = Object.assign({}, subscription.toJSON(), { extra });
```

Comment: hi Sergey, I have tried the Object.assign(), but the content of subscriptionObject is overwritten by extra, all properties from subscription object are lost. Please see my update section.

Comment: new also tried the ["extra"] approach, still when JSON.stringify(newSub), the extra part is lost.

Comment: @Franva I edited my post now that I realized you are working with the Push API. Give the latest snippet a try...

Comment: this works for me. Yes, it turns out the issue comes from subscription returned from the PushAPI. Thanks heaps for your help ~!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
newSub = {
  ...subscription, extra
}
```

you don't need to spread extra in this case.

```
sub = JSON.stringify(newSub) should result in: "{"endpoint":"dfksjfklsjkld","keys":{"pkey":"dfsfsdfsf","auth":"dfsdfsdfsd"},"extra":{"email":"dfsdfs","ip":"231342.342.342.34"}}"
```

[image]

Comment: thanks Gerrit, please see my update section, I tried your way, but the content of newSub is overwritten by extra, all properties of sub are lost

Comment: I added a screenshot, cause i don't understand from a js point of view why some property keys get eaten :)

Comment: I found out the reason, please seeSergey.K 's answer. It turns out it's the issue from PushAPI

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use like simple assignment of property

```
let subscription = {..}
const extra = {..}
```

then

```
subscription.extra = extra;
```

it should work

[image]

Comment: thanks man, this is my 1st approach that I have tried. but no luck. I consoloe.log() the newSub, I can see the extra property there, but the issue is when JSON.stringify(newSub), it lost the extra property.

Comment: i just tried and it was working, wait let me print you

Comment: i just added a screenshot of my console

Comment: thanks man, I did try it in my console and I can see it works. I have added my methods e.g. updateSubscription() and getSubscription() as-is without any modifications. Could you please review them and see if you could spot any mistakes there?

Comment: I found out the reason, please seeSergey.K 's answer. It turns out it's the issue from PushAPI.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hacky, but it looks like we don't know how the `PushSubscription` object is implemented, and it may not work as you expect...

... however it seems to convert to JSON properly using its own method (according to its API), so you may want to try something like this:

```js
const newSub = { ...JSON.parse(subscription.toJSON()), extra };
```

Thus, converting it to JSON (using the `toJSON` method in the Push API) and back to a "normal" javascript object, -then- adding the `extra` property to it.

Comment: correct, it's because PushApi implemented its own toJSON() so I have to use it.

Comment: I haven't tested it for a subscription object, but usually, despite its name, `toJSON` doesn't return JSON. It returns a value that can be serialized to JSON. So `JSON.parse` might not actually work here (it shouldn't be needed). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior